# Object not found error in dplyr group_by and count

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a count of  as a first step to calculate a percent cover for each category. The code below has worked before, but is no longer working.

I have read other posts on SO and none of them seem to capture the problem I'm experiencing.

Here is a reproducible example of what I'm trying to do:

```
 library(dplyr)

cover_data_test<- data.frame( site=c('cram','khq','k50'), 
                     treatment=c('exc','out','exc'), 
                     season=c('fall','spring','fall'),
                     transect=c(1,1,1), 
                     point=c(1,2,3),
                     ground=c('b','l','pb')
                     )
 View(cover_data_test)

  groundcover_test<- cover_data_test%>%
        group_by(season,site,treatment,transect)%>%
        count(ground)
```

I am still getting this error with the above example:

```
"Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'b' not found"
```

Any ideas about what might be going on?

Comment: Just use `dput` or `head` to copy paste your data

Comment: It doesn't seem like that particular error message would come from that code. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Another thing to try is the classic computer hack.  Restart R and/or RStudio.

Comment: I added a reproducible example that is giving me the same error.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. If I copy/paste that code into R, it runs without error. Maybe you've reassigned something over a built in variable. You can check by running `conflicts()`.

Comment: I have tried restarting R and my computer and updating with the newest version. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you add output of `sessionInfo()` to your question?

Comment: @MrFlick The `conflicts()` function helped me get to the bottom of it! "count" was listed as a conflict so I edited the code to be `groundcover_test<- cover_data_test%>%
        group_by(season,site,treatment,transect)%>%
        dplyr::count(ground)`     Adding  the double colon operator allowed it to run as expected. Thanks again!

Answer (score 12):

The `conflicts()` function helped me get to the bottom of it! "count" was listed as a conflict so I edited the code to be 
     `r
      groundcover_test<- cover_data_test %>%
            group_by(season,site,treatment,transect)%>% 
            dplyr::count(ground)`

Adding the double colon operator `dplyr::` allowed it to run as expected. Thanks again!